# 'Key' warning in antd table component when trying to load Skeleton while loading

Tags: reactjs, antd

[Image showing structure of the Table in ReactDevTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6bSE.png)

This picture shows the portion of the structure of antd Table. Its giving me this error:
`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of` Body`.`

As you can see from the picture - every component has a key. But its still dropping this error.
I have tried adding rowKey but its not helping.

Snippet of the code -

```
// other code here
  } else if (this.state.processing) {
      let dataSke = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        let y = {};
        y.title = <Skeleton.Input key={uuidv4()} style={{ width: "300px" }} />;
        y.topic_name = <Skeleton.Input key={uuidv4()} style={{ width: "200px" }} />;
        y.type = <Skeleton.Input key={uuidv4()} style={{ width: "100px" }} />;
        dataSke.push(y);
      }
      // console.log(dataSke);
      return (
        <>
          <Table
          rowKey={obj => obj.id}
            columns={this.columns}
            dataSource={dataSke}
            rowSelection={rowSelection}
          />
        </>
      );
// other code here
```

Comment: Is this `rowSelection` something from the library or do you render this?

Comment: its written by me, but the code is actually pretty much picked up from one of the many antd tables example on their site, so its pretty standard

Comment: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection-and-operation

Here's one of those rowSelection example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `key` according to the documentation

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  let y = {};
  y.key = uuidv4();
  y.title = <Skeleton.Input style={{ width: "300px" }} />;
  y.topic_name = <Skeleton.Input style={{ width: "200px" }} />;
  y.type = <Skeleton.Input style={{ width: "100px" }} />;
  dataSke.push(y);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try putting key right on that whole object and was putting the key to each of the skeleton. Smh. Atleast you saved me from a lot more random solution. Thanks. Extra eyes are always great.